# update manager to update remote software (windows)

Tags: windows, update, configuration-management, deployment

We deploy windows machines with a 3rd party application that we modify slightly (config files and images) just after we install it on the soon to be deployed systems. This application does not have any auto update feature, but does have updates come out once every couple of months in the form of new install packages. Everytime you want to update the software, you have to download it, uninstall the old one, and install the new one.

Having the client manually update the software is a no go.
RDP is not ideal either as there would be privacy issues.

Is there any good client/server update software that we can use to push updates to our clients computers from ours?

--edit
I was just looking at the System Center Configuration Manager
http://bit.ly/lxzoBr

At first glance it looks promising. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have good experiences with adminarsenal's [PDQ Deploy](http://www.adminarsenal.com). It can push exe, MSI, batch, etc. files to remote machines. It can also sync with Active Directory and is agentless. But it is for pushing only, the machines have to be online also. You can setup schedules but it won't work if the client is powered down.
Depending on how much clients you have and how big your enviroment is, SCCM maybe a bit over the top for your needs.

Comment: does it support post install modifications? maybe using scripts to change some of the resources that the newly install application uses?

Comment: Yes, you can do multiple steps but only in the Pro version i think. Execute scripts, reg-files and so on. There is a free version with limited features and a 30-day-trial for the Pro version.